# PySpark partial Match colum to dictionary values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3 : "value3"}
```

and a dataframe test_dta with single column:

```
   Col
 value1
 value2 
 value3
 wrong_value
 value1value4
 ...
```

My expected results is to filter for the dataframe where it will ony return the rows that have a partial match with the dictionary value. I.e.

```
Colu          
value1      
value2      
value3      
value1value4
```

I have tried approaches such as:

```
test_dta.filter(test_dta.Colu.contains(list(dict.values())))
```

but returns an error message.

May I know the correct/ other ways to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Contains`** checks the **substring exists** in the string and `.isin` checks if any **value match** found in *list of items* but your case is to match string based on list.

Instead use **`.rlike`** we can generate **`or(|)`** condition and filter only the matching rows.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+------------+
#|         Col|
#+------------+
#|      value1|
#|      value2|
#|      value3|
#|       wrong|
#|value1value2|
#+------------+
dict = {'key1': "value1", 'key2': "value2", 'key3' : "value3"}

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#filter using rlike and generate expression dynamically based on dict.values
df.filter(col("Col").rlike("|".join(["(" +l+")" for l in list(dict.values())]))).show()
#+------------+
#|         Col|
#+------------+
#|      value1|
#|      value2|
#|      value3|
#|value1value2|
#+------------+
```